# is it possible to display solid c3 grid lines via CSS instead of default dashed grid line?

Tags: css, graph, c3.js, gridlines

is there a way to achieve solid c3 grid lines via css without explicitly declaring line values?

Example:

C3's basic [Grid Line example](https://c3js.org/samples/options_gridline.html)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 120, 200]
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        x: {
            show: true
        },
        y: {
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```

In general, I've discovered that I can change the default styling of the grid with the following CSS:

```
.c3 .c3-grid line {
  stroke: pink,       
  stroke-width: 4,  -> if width can be changed, why can't I use css to make grid line solid?
  opacity: 0.3,      
  fill: blue,       
}
```

[image of how the CSS above looks with the attributes listed above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZdfY.png)

I know that solid grid lines can be achieved by explicitly declaring them like this

Example:

C3 [Style for Grid example](https://c3js.org/samples/style_grid.html)

When I say *explicitly declaring* them I'm referring to the fact that in order to display solid grid lines you have to actually give the lines you want to be displayed. Like the example below:

```
grid: {
    x: {
        lines: [{value: 2}, {value: 4}]
    },
    y: {
        lines: [{value: 500}, {value: 800}]
    }
}
```

**So I ask, is it possible to use css to make c3's default dashed grid line a solid line?**

It seems silly that you can't just use something like:

```
.c3 .c3-grid line {
      stroke: pink,       
      stroke-width: 4,
      opacity: 0.3,      
      fill: blue,
      dashed: false,   <-- insert whatever property would give  me solid grid lines
    }
```

I've seen one other person ask a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/c3js/grid%7Csort:date/c3js/9zk44L1pE6g/gOx0Wcq5CgAJ)

Answer (score 8):

I feel quite silly, after spending lots of time prepping my notes to ask my first question on Stack Overflow. A colleague mentioned that I should try using the property, `stroke-dasharray: 0;`.

Thus,

```
.c3 .c3-grid line {
  stroke: pink;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;  <--- turns dashed lines solid
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray), the ***stroke-dasharray*** attribute is a presentation attribute defining the pattern of dashes and gaps used to paint the outline of the shape.

After locating the correct CSS property I was able to find all sorts of resources on the finer points of using *stroke-dasharray*.

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/
- https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp

In short, it's very possible to use CSS to style a c3 grid line - if you know what property to use.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question & self-answer. Useful stuff to know.